# Rename multiple sequentially numbered files and change numbering format using BASH?

Tags: image, bash, rename, batch-processing

I have a bunch of sequentially named files in this format: `imageXXX.jpg`. So it would be like `image001.jpg` and onward. I just want to keep the number part of this, and get rid of the prepended `0`'s. So instead, that file would be named `1.jpg`. How could I achieve this using Bash?

Comment: @msw, that looks like an answer rather than a comment. If you make it an answer, it can be accepted or upvoted so the system will know the question has been answered.

Comment: @msw that didn't seem to work...

Comment: @TreyK: if you have any respect for the people you're asking to help you, please do better than "didn't seem to work". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/3763866#3763866

Comment: @LarsH I wouldn't say it's a matter of respect, but you have a good point. It failed silently, I probably should have mentioned that. Rename command is installed on the server.

Comment: @TreyK, Nothing personal... I got a little carried away... I see so many q's that say "it didn't work" without giving any specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux the venerable Perl utility [rename](http://metacpan.org/pod/File::Rename) is friendly:

```
$ rename 's/^image0+//' image*.jpg
```

You should be aware that stripping leading zeros will ruin the sort order, that is `*.jpg` orders like:

```
1.jpg
10.jpg
11.jpg
...
2.jpg
20.jpg
```

If you want to keep the order just use

```
$ rename 's/^image//' image*.jpg
```

instead.

### added in response to system identification

You can likely script it in bash alone, but it would be non-trivial and the failure cases really need to be handled correctly. Yeah, hoisting Perl onto a system is non-trivial too, but it is easy and that wheel's already been invented

> Fedora Core 8 Perl RPM: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/5152898/dir/fedora_8/com/perl-5.8.8-30.n0i.51.fc8.i386.rpm.html
>   CPAN rename: http://metacpan.org/pod/File::Rename

### added in response to silent failure

`rename` like `chmod` will complain if you give it malformed arguments, but both are silent if what you request has no effect. For example

```
$ ls -l junk
-rw-r--r-- 1 msw msw 0 2010-09-24 01:59 junk
$ chmod 688 junk
chmod: invalid mode: '688'
$ chmod 644 junk    # was already 644 mode, nothing happened no error
$ rename 's/bob/alice/' ju*k    
# there was no 'bob' in 'junk' to substitute, no change, no error
$ ls -l junk
-rw-r--r-- 1 msw msw 0 2010-09-24 01:59 junk
$ rename 's/un/ac/' j*k  # but there is an 'un' in 'junk', change it
$ ls -l j*k
-rw-r--r-- 1 msw msw 0 2010-09-24 01:59 jack
```

You can make `rename` less silent:

```
$ rename --verbose 's/ac/er/' j*k
jack renamed as jerk
$ rename --verbose 's/ac/er/' j*k   # nothing to rename
$
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help, but for some reason it didn't seem to rename the files on our server. The command you posted above failed silently.

Answer (score 3):

Pure Bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in image*.jpg; do mv "$f" "${f/#image*(0)}"; done
```

Additional code could check for name collisions or handle other error conditions. You could use `mv -i` to prompt before files are overwritten.

Comment: +1: giving the people what they ask for. @TreyK, this does one trick, rename and the commands it takes does the next job and plenty others too. Moreover, the Perl `s`/ubstit/ute/ command used is seen throughout Unix tools; you'll probably see it again.